# Can i have multi module with loopback models?

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, loopbackjs

I am new to loopback framework.
My application will have too many models.
I want put it different folders.For Example i want have this structure :

```
./server/models/frontend/user/user.js
./server/models/frontend/user/userType.js
./server/models/backend/permission.js
```

Can deploy this structure?
If i use this structure can i use loopback CLI?
Do you have any better way to categorize my models?

Comment: What models will be in the `frontend` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This structure can be deployed and you can use the loopback CLI.

Loopback allows you to customize the configuration for the models. You can specify where the application should load your models by specifying the directories in the `sources` property of the `model-config.json` file. A simple example would be this:

**server/model-config.json**

```
"_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../server/models/frontend/user",
      "../server/models/backend"
    ]
  },
```

You can view the sample configuration here: [Loopback example model configuration](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-getting-started/blob/master/server/model-config.json)

Comment: It worked for me but how can i use CLI for generate frontend/backend models?