# Implement Multi-tenancy in Loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, multi-tenant

We are already using `loopback` as our backend server for `REST APIs`.

Now our product demands to have multi tenancy in our system i.e seperate database per user.

So after searching for an hour , we got something like [Loopback-MultiTenancy POC Sample](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-multitenant-poc).

The sample looks nice and exact what we need , though there are some issues we are facing using this poc and also at architecture level.

This POC create seperate folders per `tenant`. Each `tenant` folder has its own `config` , own `datasource` and its own `models` ,which is fine. But what we have is , we have common models for all users.

So whenever new user gets created , will have to create new tenant folder and move all `models` inside that folder either manually or using some script.

But when we gonna have 100 of users and say we want to change a particular model schema , so what it requires is reflect the changes in all other tenant folders also, Which is kind of very very troublesome for us.

So we are looking for better solution which doesnt ask for duplication and also serves the purpose , as of loopback.

We are kind of stuck , need some help or advice.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you do maybe specify that models are loaded from a single location, by using the sources property? That way all your users will load the same model files
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35874951/can-i-have-multi-module-with-loopback-models?rq=1

Comment: @Acapulco : The above configuration is completely different, if you see the link attached. It creates diff diff folder which has its own config and its own models.. in my case , each folder gonna have same models and the datasource name going to be different.